# C Thread scheduling (and asm)

Tags: c, multithreading, assembly, variable-assignment

I'm currently writing up my own threading library. And I am unable to debug an unhandled exception "Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun". Below is the code in question that causes the unhandled exception

```
void Scheduler()
{

  void *curr_esp;
  TCB* next_thread = ready_queue->data;
  popFront(&ready_queue);
  __asm
  {
pushad
mov curr_esp, esp
  }
  curr_thread->esp = curr_esp;

  if (curr_thread->status == RUNNING)
  {
    curr_thread->status = READY;
    Enqueue(curr_thread, &ready_queue);

  }

  curr_thread = next_thread;

  if (curr_thread->status == READY)
  {
    curr_thread->status = RUNNING;

    curr_esp = next_thread->esp;
__asm
{
  mov esp, curr_esp
  popad
}

 }

 else if (curr_thread->status == NEW)
 {
    curr_thread->status = RUNNING;
    curr_thread->params = (curr_thread->fn)(curr_thread->params);
    __asm
    {
      mov esp,curr_esp
    }
    if (curr_thread->status == RUNNING)
    {
       thread_exit(curr_thread->params);
    }

  }
}
```

This is the main doing the spin function that's supposed to run the threadlib and thd_yield basically just calls my scheduler

```
void *spin1(void *a)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i< 20; i++)
    {
        printf("SPIN1\n");
        if((i+1)%4==0)
            thd_yield();
    }
    return NULL;
}

void* spin2(void *a)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i< 20; i++)
    {
        printf("SPIN2\n");
        if((i+1)%4==0)
            thd_yield();
    }
    return NULL;
}


 int main()
{       
    thread_id_ id;
    thd_init();
    id = new_thd(spin2, NULL);
    spin1(NULL);
}
```

The output is supposed to be 5 sets of 4 "spin1"s and "spin2"s alternating.

spin1
spin1
spin1
spin1
spin2
spin2
spin2
spin2
spin1
..

The code works perfectly fine for the first 2 sets of "spin1"s and 1 , but gives me an unhandled exception on the 2nd set of "spin2"s. I have checked the stack pointers being stored and retrieved and they are correctly stored and retrieved, the linked list storage and memory allocations. What's worse is that I'm not shown which line is causing the error.

NOTE: I'm not allow to use any thread system calls and it has to be in C.

Here is my TCB struct if it helps

```
typedef struct _TCB_
{
  /* Unique ID*/
  thread_id_ id;
  /* Thread status*/
  enum ThreadState status;
  /* ID of next thread*/
  thread_id_ wait_id;

  void *esp;

  void *(*fn)(void*);

  void *params;

  void *stack;

}TCB;
```

I will gladly share my source file if it assists you in solving this issue.

Comment: This article may give you some clues https://kallanreed.wordpress.com/2015/02/14/disabling-the-stack-cookie-generation-in-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: Seems like the answer to this question might depend on which version of which compiler you are using and, on which options you are compiling with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, something is interfering with the stack cookie.

Stack cookie is calculated and stored at the end of the current stack frame before executing the function code. When the function code execution is over it's being validated. In case of buffer overrun, it gets overwritten and the validation fails. This is why it can't report you a line that caused the problem.

There might be multiple reasons for this exception in your case. Since it's hard to tell without having the whole code, I will make some assumptions:

- You may actually have a *buffer overrun*. The eseast way to test is to disable the *stack cookie security check*, and see if you have "Access violation" exception. Even if you don't, it still may be a *buffer overrun*.
- Stack pointers of different threads are pointing to an overlapping memory region. This may happen if you're not allocating enough memory for the stack - which is a *buffer overrun* anyways.
- Very unlikely, but your code may be right, but it's not compatible with the *stack cookie security check*, so you have to make it compatible or disable the check. The only recommendation here is to enable *Assembler Output* and check it.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer. If its possible, can I send you my source files? Maybe you can spot something I couldn't for hours.

Comment: I really think it would be better for your studies to spot it yourself.

Comment: I've tried everything I can think of, which is why I'm posting here. I usually am able to debug my own work, but this really feels like banging my head against a wall. I've done everything i can possibly think of. 
Rewriting my linked list, 
Rewriting the entire scheduler (4 times now),
Using the Memory Diagnostic tool to check for unintentional memory allocations and deallocations, all check out correctly.
Checking the stack pointers I've manipulated through asm.
And I cannot still cannot see anything wrong.

Comment: @DanA: Try disabling stack cookies.  You're using inline asm to swap thread stacks, so I think clover's 3rd point is most likely and stack-checks may be breaking your otherwise-ok code.  OTOH, swapping out esp and ebp in the middle of code that accesses some local variables seems pretty risky.  Definitely check the compiler-generated asm.  You may need to write more of the context-switch in asm.